# Android how to put a horizontal bar between preferences

Tags: java, android

I've searched long and hard. I'd like to put a thick black horizontal line between two preferences.. sounds simple enough. But no one has a working answer for me! (Meaning, nothing so far that i've seen on stackoverflow or google.)

Here's where I want it:

```
<Preference
    android:key="problem"

    android:onClick="problemP"
    android:title="Report a Problem"/>
<Preference
    android:key="feedback"
    android:onClick="feedbackF"
    android:title="General Feedback"/>
```

Between the two!

Comment: Those aren't PreferenceCategories.

Comment: Sorry - edited. I mean preferences.

Comment: Since Android's Preference API uses a ListView with a horizontal line item decoration, you can't really do what you want. You can make a layout with a horizontal line and set that as the layout resource for a Preference you put between those two, and set it as disabled and not-clickable, which might work.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was declaring a custom view for my preference and adding a divider at the end, like this:

```
<Preference
    android:title="..."
    ...
    android:layout="@layout/preference_list_item"
    />
```

And then in **`preference_list_item.xml`**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical>
    .
    .
    .
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        abdroid:background="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Disabling the preference and making it unclickable will prevent the default ListView dividers from showing around the Preference, for a slightly cleaner look.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/prefBar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3px"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    >

</ImageView>
```

So I set the layout to a Prefeence to this Layout and i have a 3px high black bar! Looks great.